# Send array from node.js and use client side

Tags: node.js, express, post, get

Im a beginner with node.js so bear with me please :D

Simple task: I use `express` and I want to send an array, lets say `["item1", "item2"]` from a node server to a client that calls the server with a `get` method. When I tried this, I stumbled upon the `CORS` error.

I also thought about doing a this through a `post`:

-`client`:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".testButton").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:3000/test_post",
                type: "post",
                data: "sent",
                success: function () {}
            });
     });
```

-`server`:

```
app.post('/Quiz_post', function (req, res) {
  res.send(["item1", "item2"]);
});
```

But this also doesnt work. Now I am trying to use `cross-fetch` client side. Could you please guide me a bit? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in ur app.js to enable CORS.

npm i cors in the project 1st

```
var cors = require('cors');

var app= express(); //After this line of code add the code below

app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Thanks. This removed the CORS err. Now I am figuring out the next part: sending the actual array/json form the server and using it on the client.

Comment: To send JSON data back just res.json(Object/array). You can test your server api by using postman

Comment: Already did it, but thank you the comment. Thanks a lot for the answer! You helped me a lot :)